# java- Como puedo realizar las preguntas correctamente en un bucle do-while? me salta preguntas

Tags: java, poo, bucles

El programa me salta preguntas si coloco un espacio en mi respuesta, pero si coloco un nextLine en las preguntas tambien me salta respuestas. Como se podría solucionar?

Hace Esto:

```
Quiere registrar una pelicula?(S/N)
s
Indique el titulo de la pelicula:el padrino
Indique el autor de la pelicula:Pulse un numero para elegir el formato de la pelicula:
1.-Wav
2.-MP3
3.-midi
4.-avi
5.-mov
6.-mpg
7.-cdAudio
8.-DVD
```

**Main**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import Act2.Multimedia.Format;


public class Main {
    static ArrayList <Pelicula> peliculas = new ArrayList<Pelicula>();
    static Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String titol;
        String autor;
        Format format;
        int durada;
        String actor;
        String actriu;
        String respuesta;
        String respuesta2;
        String respuesta3;

        //empezamos un bucle mientras el usuario desee insertar mas usuarios
        do {    
            System.out.println("Quiere registrar una pelicula?(S/N)");
            respuesta = lector.next();

            if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {

                System.out.print("Indique el titulo de la pelicula:");
                titol = lector.next();
                System.out.print("Indique el autor de la pelicula:");
                autor = lector.next();
                formato();
                System.out.print("Indique la duracion de la pelicula:");
                durada = lector.nextInt();
                System.out.print("La pelicula tiene un actor?(s/n)");
                respuesta2 = lector.next();
                if(respuesta2.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                    System.out.print("Indique el actor principal de la pelicula:");
                    actor = lector.next();
                    System.out.print("La pelicula tiene una actriz?(s/n)");
                    respuesta3 = lector.next();
                    if(respuesta3.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                        System.out.print("Indique la actriz principal de la pelicula:");
                        actriu = lector.next();
                        peliculas.add(new Pelicula(titol,autor,formato(),durada,actor,actriu));
                    }
                    else {
                        peliculas.add(new Pelicula(titol,autor,formato(),durada,actor));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("La pelicula tiene una actriz?(s/n)");
                    respuesta3 = lector.next();
                    if(respuesta3.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                        System.out.print("Indique la actriz principal de la pelicula:");
                        actriu = lector.next();
                        peliculas.add(new Pelicula(titol,autor,formato(),durada,actriu));
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No puede haber una pelicula sin actor ni actriz");
                    }
                }

            }

        }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")); //mientras la respuesta sea s

        listadoPeliculas();
        System.out.printf("Hay peliculas iguales? %b \n", peliculas.equals(peliculas));

    }

    public static void listadoPeliculas() { //metodo para imprimir un listado de peliculas
        //imprimimos el listado de peliculas el arraylist es recorrido por un for
        System.out.println("\n**Peliculas**");
        if(peliculas.size() > 0 ) {
            for(Pelicula p: peliculas) {    
                System.out.println("\n"+p.toString());
            }   
            System.out.println("\n************************\n");
        }else {
            System.out.println("---------------");
        }
    }

    public static Format formato(){ //metodo para elegir el formato
        System.out.print("Pulse un numero para elegir el formato de la pelicula:\n1.-Wav"
                + "\n2.-MP3\n3.-midi\n4.-avi\n5.-mov\n6.-mpg\n7.-cdAudio\n8.-DVD");
        int opcion = lector.nextInt();

        switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            return Multimedia.Format.wav;
        case 2:
            return Multimedia.Format.mp3;
        case 3:
            return Multimedia.Format.midi;
        case 4:
            return Multimedia.Format.avi;
        case 5:
            return Multimedia.Format.mov;
        case 6:
            return Multimedia.Format.mpg;
        case 7:
            return Multimedia.Format.cdaudio;
        case 8:
            return Multimedia.Format.DVD;
        default:
            return Multimedia.Format.DVD;
        }
    }

}
```

**Objeto Multimedia**

```
public class Multimedia {

    public enum Format{wav,mp3,midi,avi,mov,mpg,cdaudio,DVD};

    private String titol;
    private String autor;
    private Format format;
    private int durada;

    //constructor
    public Multimedia(String titol, String autor, Format format, int durada) {
        this.titol = titol;
        this.autor = autor;
        this.format = format;
        this.durada = durada;
    }

    public String getTitol() {
        return titol;
    }

    public void setTitol(String titol) {
        this.titol = titol;
    }

    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public Format getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(Format format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public int getDurada() {
        return durada;
    }

    public void setDurada(int durada) {
        this.durada = durada;
    }

    //metodo equals per a que retorne true si titol y autor son iguals / false en cas contrari
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Multimedia iguales = (Multimedia) obj;
        return iguales.autor.equalsIgnoreCase(this.autor) &&
                iguales.titol.equalsIgnoreCase(this.titol);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Titulo=" + titol + ", Autor=" + autor + ", Formato=" + format + ", Duracion=" + durada;
    }


}
```

**Objeto pelicula**

```
public class Pelicula extends Multimedia{

    private String actor;
    private String actriu;


    public Pelicula(String titol, String autor, Format format, int durada, String actor, String actriu) {
        super(titol, autor, format, durada);
        this.actor = actor;
        this.actriu = actriu;
    }



    public Pelicula( String actriu, String titol, String autor, Format format, int durada) {
        super(titol, autor, format, durada);
        this.actriu = actriu;
    }



    public Pelicula(String titol, String autor, Format format, int durada, String actor) {
        super(titol, autor, format, durada);
        this.actor = actor;
    }



    public String getActor() {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(String actor) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    public String getActriu() {
        return actriu;
    }

    public void setActriu(String actriu) {
        this.actriu = actriu;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+" actor=" + actor + ", actriz=" + actriu;
    }


    public String actor() {
        return super.toString()+" actor=" + actor;
    }

    public String actriz() {
        return super.toString()+" actriz=" + actriu;
    }

}
```

Comment: Simplemente cambia todo a `nextLine()` y no te olvides de limpiar el búfer cuando uses `nextInt()`, `nextFloat`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > El programa me salta preguntas si coloco un espacio en mi respuesta, pero si coloco un nextLine en las preguntas tambien me salta respuestas. Como se podría solucionar?

El problema radica en la forma como funciona el método [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)). Básicamente este método solo leerá caracteres hasta encontrar el primer espacio en el **búfer del teclado** (donde se almacenan los caracteres cuando se escribe por teclado).

Es decir, cuando este código se ejecute:

```java
System.out.println("Quiere registrar una pelicula?(S/N)");
respuesta = lector.next();
```

El búfer estará limpio, por lo tanto, cuando el usuario escriba la `s`, el búfer seguirá estando limpio.

Cuando se ejecute el código #2:

```java
System.out.print("Indique el titulo de la pelicula:");
titol = lector.next();
```

El programa se pausará, sin embargo, cuando el usuario escriba `el padrino`, el método `next()` solo leerá la palabra `el` (porque solo leerá hasta encontrar el primer espacio), pero el resto de caracteres quedarán en el búfer del teclado, haciendo que el búfer se quede sucio.

Cuando se ejecute el código #3:

```java
System.out.print("Indique el autor de la pelicula:");
autor = lector.next();
```

No se pausará el programa, debido a que, el búfer se quedó sucio, ya que la palabra `padrino` no se pudo leer anteriormente y esto hizo que el método `next()` lea los caracteres actuales que tenga el búfer del teclado (es decir `padrino`) y esto hace que la pregunta se salte.

**Solución:** Deberías de usar el método [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()). Este método lee todos los caracteres que estén en el  búfer del teclado, es la contraparte del método [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)).

También recalco que el método [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) dejará sucio el búfer del teclado. Es decir, si ingresaste por teclado un `25`, el búfer quedaría con un salto de línea, entonces cuando trates de pedir otra información con el método `nextLine()`, no te pausará el programa, debido a que, el método leerá el caracter que tenga el búfer (en este caso un `\n`).

Ejemplo:

```java
System.out.print("Indique la duracion de la pelicula:");
durada = lector.nextInt();
System.out.print("La pelicula tiene un actor?(s/n)");
respuesta2 = lector.nextLine();
```

Cuando se ejecute `nextInt()` y se escriba `12`, el búfer quedará con `\n`.

Cuando se ejecute `nextLine()`, no pausará el programa a la espera de una opción, por lo tanto, leerá el salto de línea y se saltará la pregunta.

**Solución:** Limpiar el búfer del teclado antes de invocar el método `nextLine()`.

```java
System.out.print("Indique la duracion de la pelicula:");
durada = lector.nextInt();
lector.nextLine();//limpia el búfer del teclado
System.out.print("La pelicula tiene un actor?(s/n)");
respuesta2 = lector.nextLine();
```

Comment: Wau muchisimas gracias por responderme, llevo varios dias con esta duda, la unica solucion que habia encontrado era colocar next en vez de nextLine pero en este ejercicio me he quedado que no sabia hacia donde tirar.